# Ember Data duplicate record with undefined attributes

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, ember-data

So I am trying to create a new record in the store and save it to my api, but I am getting some strange behavior. I send json to the api and the api sends back json in the response that is identical to the json sent except it has an id. After Ember Data has got the json back it creates two records in the store, one with the correct data and one with undefined attributes. (the id's are the same)

Let me try to show you what is happening.

The json sent to the api.

```
"person": {
    "fname": "new",
    "lname": "user"
}
```

The json in the response.

```
"person": {
    "id": "1",
    "fname": "new",
    "lname": "user"
}
```

When I look at the data in Ember Inspector.

```
id            fname            lname
1             new              user
1             undefined        undefined
```

What could be causing Ember Data to create this duplicate record?

Let me know if you need any more information. Thanks for any help.

Edit:
Here is my model and adapter.

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend ({
    fname: DS.attr('string'),
    lname: DS.attr('string') 
});
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: "http://myapihost"
});
```

Comment: How are you saving the model? Can you share the code for your model and adapter? Does this happen if you try creating and saving a model in the console?

Comment: This is the model.
`App.Person = DS.Model.extend ({
  fname: DS.attr('string'),
  lname: DS.attr('string')
});`

And the adapter.
`App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({host: "http://myapihost"});`

Comment: I got exactly the same problem, did you found a solution?